# Setting UTF-8 in Google App Engine using JAX RS

Tags: google-app-engine, utf-8

Passing values such as ÅÄÖ is getting converted to ??? on reaching the server.

```
JQuery ajax call is as follows:
 $.ajax({
        url: 'some url here',
        type: 'post',
        contentType:"application/xml;charset=utf-8",
        scriptCharset: "utf-8" ,
        data: 'some data here',
        success: function(data, status) {
           //code...            
        }
    });
```

Added

```
<env-variables>
        <env-var name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
    </env-variables>
```

in appengine-web.xml

It works in local system but doesn't work on GAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it using
msg = new String(msg.getBytes("UTF8"), "UTF8");